# Cannot load 'tm' package in R

Tags: r, tm

This is the first time I am trying to install and load `tm` package in R and so far I am unsuccessful. Here is my machine info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0
```

I do the installation by running the following code:

```
install.packages('tm', repos = 'https://cran.r-project.org', dependencies = T)
```

which give me the following messages:

```
Warning in install.packages :
dependencies ‘Rcampdf’, ‘Rgraphviz’, ‘Rpoppler’, ‘tm.lexicon.GeneralInquirer’ are not available
also installing the dependencies ‘NLP’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘slam’, ‘BH’, ‘filehash’, ‘SnowballC’, ‘XML’
...
...
package ‘NLP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘BH’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘filehash’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘SnowballC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘XML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

But when I try to load the package it gives me the following error:

```
load('tm')
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'tm', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Appreciate any help/words of wisdom

Comment: To load the library, type: `library(tm)`

Answer (score 1):

The load() function reloads previously saved data sets.

You're looking for the library() function, as @Marco Sandri pointed out in the comments.

Try:

```
library(tm)
```